# Nginx : Rewrite a range of location

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to rewrite multiple locations (with different IPs) for multiple proxies with Nginx.

I've tried this :

```
location ~/target/(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass  https://$ip;
    rewrite ^/target_ip/$ip/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

but it's unfortunately not removing /target/ip :

> The requested URL /target/192.168.10.3/cgi-bin/luci was not found on this server.

This way is working :

```
location ~/target/(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass  https://$ip;
    if ($ip = "192.168.10.3") { 
        rewrite ^/target_ip/192.168.10.3/(.*) /$1 break;
    }
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

However, I have to specify an if statement for each IP. I need something more compact.

Do you have any tips ?

Thanks!

--------------- EDIT ---------------

Here is the solution, thanks to Richard Smith :

```
location ~/target/(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_pass  https://$ip;
rewrite ^/target_ip/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 break;
proxy_intercept_errors off;
proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Comment: Use the same regular expression: `rewrite ^/target_ip/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/(.*)$ /$1 break;` - or more simply: `rewrite ^/target_ip/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 break;`

Comment: I didn't think about that way. It's working perfectly, thank you very much !